# Scrape A order Value on Amazon, add to the relevant scraped product

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am working with a small scraper, to scrape a few products on Amazon's page.

Currently I am able to scrape (after passing an starting URL, where I search for a specific item):

1. The titles of all the products on the page
2. The URL's of all the products on the page
3. The ASIN number of all the products on the page

**But what I can't do**: if you dive into the HTML of Amazon, you see that the order of products are showed with "search_result_X" (where X is the number, so 0 = first one on the page, 30 the 31st product on the page and so on).

[image]

**How can I add the 'search_result_x' (the order), to each product?** So I hope to get the scraped result like this (note: if you see the code below, the only thing missing is the Order_Number):

```
{'Title_Product': Title ASDF, 'Link_Product': 'www.asdf.com', 'ASIN_Product' = 'B12345689', Order_Number = '1'},     {'Title_Product': Title_2 ASDF, 'Link_Product': 'www.asdf2.com', 'ASIN_Product' = 'B12345682', Order_Number = '2'}
```

So a big JSON file, and the only column that is missing, is the "Order_Number" of the column (the order on which a product appeared.

Code so far (retrieved from Stack, and from Thiago):

```
import os
from twisted.internet import reactor
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
import re

class AmazonProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "AmazonDeals"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]
    #Use working product URL below
    start_urls = [
            "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=trimmer&ref=nb_sb_noss_2"]

## Check this link, could be usefull https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpHgsdQhsXo
    custom_settings = {
            'FEED_URI' : 'Asin_Titles.json',
            'FEED_FORMAT' : 'json'
            }
    def parse(self, response):
        Link = response.css('.a-text-normal').css('a::attr(href)').extract()
        Title = response.css('span.a-text-normal').css('::text').extract()
        OrderNumber = response.css("div::attr(data-index)").get()     

        # for each product, create AmazonItem, populate the fields and yield the item
        for result in zip(Link,Title):
            item = AmazonItem()
            item['title_Product'] = result[1]
            item['link_Product'] = result[0]
            # Extract ASIN from link
            ASIN = re.findall(r"(?<=dp/)[A-Z0-9]{10}",result[0])[0]
            item['ASIN_Product'] = ASIN
            item['url_Response'] = response.url

            # Test to get the Order Number @
            item['Order_Number'] = OrderNumber
            yield item

class AmazonItem(scrapy.Item):
    title_Product = scrapy.Field()
    link_Product = scrapy.Field()
    ASIN_Product = scrapy.Field()
    url_Response = scrapy.Field()
    Order_Number = scrapy.Field() 


configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
runner = CrawlerRunner()

d = runner.crawl(AmazonProductSpider)
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())



reactor.run() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That property is generated by javascript after the page load. If you check the "*View Page Source*" in your browser, you will see that it doesn't exist in the response body.
However, it does have a `data-index` property that may interest you. E.g.

```html
<div data-asin="B00H2B4H2M" data-index="5" class="..." ></div>
```

**Edit:**

And to get that, you can use something:

```py
response.css("div::attr(data-index)").get()
```

or

```py
response.xpath(".//div/@data-index").get()
```

**EDIT2:**

Besides that, I suggest you loop over the search results and then find each product details, instead of selecting every field and try to zip them together. Eg.

```
def parse(self, response):
    for product in response.css('.s-result-item'): 
        item = AmazonItem()
        item['asin'] = product.css('::attr(data-asin)').get()
        item['index'] = product.css('::attr(data-index)').get()
        item['link'] = product.css('.a-text-normal::attr(href)').get() 
        # And so on 
        # ...
        yield item
```

Comment: Thanks @Thiago, can you help me with getting the number "5" in your example? Because I tried to retrieve that number, with an Xpath (using contains), unfortunately it ask for the a value of the data-index.. which is what is need of course.

Comment: Check it now :)

Comment: Thank you very much Thiago! I tried to integrate your code in my script (see edited script above), but I only receive number = 0 (if I run the script). Do you have an idea what is going wrong? Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: That was an example, you should adapt it to the correct selector. See my last edit

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!!

Comment: @ThiagoCurvelo I am using your example, also the (response.css('.s-result-item')) part. But do you know why it is not including the intended parts after the .s-result-item? The reason for asking is that I need to include if a product is sponsored or not (but that part is captured in the URL in "s-impression-logger"). Per product, the information is in the intended part after your s-result-item. Hope that you can help :-)

Comment: @ThiagoCurvelo : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56965738/scrape-a-tag-from-amazon