# Scrape a tag from Amazon

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to Scrape a Tag from Amazon.

For [this site](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=shaver%20for%20men&i=beauty&ref=nb_sb_noss_2) I try to scrape all the product titles, and the price. The scraped data is like this:

```
Title    Price
 A        169.99
 B        79.55
 C        39.96
 D        19.90       
 E        34.99
```

But, I would love to scrape the "Sponsored" tag (see **yellow mark** in the screenshot below. Blue part is to respect the brands).

[image: Example of the desired tag to scrape]

The desired output:

```
Title    Price       Sponsored_Tag
 A        169.99      Yes
 B        79.55       Yes
 C        39.96       No
 D        19.90       No
 E        34.99       No
```

**What have I tried?**

I used Python & Scrapy. You can see the item "test", where I tried to catch sponsored on multiple ways. They all failed. Will be great if we can add some changes to the code below (because I use this code for other processes as well).

Many thanks!

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
#import re

class AmazonProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "AmazonDeals"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]

    start_urls = [
            "https://www.amazon.com/s?=shaver+for+men&i=beauty&ref=nb_sb_noss_2"]

    custom_settings = {
            'FEED_URI' : 'Asin_Titles.json',
            'FEED_FORMAT' : 'json'
            }
    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.css('.s-result-item'): 
            item = AmazonItem()

            #item['test'] = product.css('.s-info-icon').get()
            #item['test'] = product.css('.s-min-height-extra-large').get()
            item['test'] = product.css('.a-spacing-micro').get()

            yield item


class AmazonItem(scrapy.Item):
    test = scrapy.Field()


configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
runner = CrawlerRunner()

d = runner.crawl(AmazonProductSpider)
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

**Update: this is what we have in "product"**

It looks like I didn't captured the 'sponsored' tag as well...

```
"items": "<div data-asin=\"B01859QHJU\" data-index=\"0\" class=\"sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 s-result-item sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32\"><div class=\"sg-col-inner\">\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<div class=\"s-expand-height s-include-content-margin s-border-bottom\">\n<div class=\"a-section a-spacing-medium\">\n\n\n<div class=\"sg-row\">\n  <div class=\"sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32\"><div class=\"sg-col-inner\">\n        <div class=\"a-section a-spacing-micro s-min-height-extra-large\">\n            \n                \n\n\n<span aria-label=\"Amazon's Choice\">\n    \n\n\n\n\n<a class=\"a-link-normal\" href=\"/Philips-Norelco-Electric-S1560-81/dp/B01859QHJU/ref=ice_ac_b_dpb\">\n    \n        \n            \n                \n\n\n\n\n<span data-component-type=\"s-status-badge-component\" data-component-props='{\"badgeType\":\"amazons-choice\",\"asin\":\"B01859QHJU\"}' class=\"rush-component\">\n  <div class=\"a-row a-badge-region\"><span id=\"B01859QHJU\" class=\"a-badge\" aria-labelledby=\"B01859QHJU-label B01859QHJU-supplementary\" data-a-badge-supplementary-position=\"right\" tabindex=\"0\" data-a-badge-type=\"status\"><span id=\"B01859QHJU-label\" class=\"a-badge-label\" data-a-badge-color=\"sx-gulfstream\" aria-hidden=\"true\"><span class=\"a-badge-label-inner a-text-ellipsis\">\n    \n      <span class=\"a-badge-text\" data-a-badge-color=\"sx-cloud\">Amazon's </span>\n    \n      <span class=\"a-badge-text\" data-a-badge-color=\"ac-orange\">Choice</span>\n    \n  </span></span><span id=\"B01859QHJU-supplementary\" class=\"a-badge-supplementary-text a-text-ellipsis\" aria-hidden=\"true\">for electric razor</span></span></div>\n</span>\n\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n\n</span>\n\n            \n        </div>\n    </div></div>\n</div>\n\n<div class=\"sg-row\">\n  <div class=\"sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32\"><div class=\"sg-col-inner\">\n        \n        <div class=\"a-section a-spacing-none\">\n            \n\n\n\n\n\n<span data-component-type=\"s-product-image\" class=\"rush-component\">\n    \n    <a class=\"a-link-normal\" href=\"/Philips-Norelco-Electric-S1560-81/dp/B01859QHJU\">\n        <div class=\"a-section aok-relative s-image-square-aspect\">\n            \n                \n                    <img src=\"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61JJ1+ygJfL._AC_UL320_.jpg\" class=\"s-image\" alt=\"Philips Norelco Electric Shaver 2100, S1560/81\" srcset=\"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61JJ1+ygJfL._AC_UL320_.jpg 1x, https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61JJ1+ygJfL._AC_UL480_QL65_.jpg 1.5x, https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61JJ1+ygJfL._AC_UL640_QL65_.jpg 2x, https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61JJ1+ygJfL._AC_UL800_QL65_.jpg 2.5x, https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61JJ1+ygJfL._AC_UL960_QL65_.jpg 3x\" data-image-index=\"0\" data-image-load=\"\" data-image-latency=\"s-product-image\" data-image-source-density=\"1\" onload=\"window.uet &amp;&amp; uet('cf')\">\n                \n                \n            \n        </div>\n    </a>\n</span>\n\n        </div>\n        \n  </div></div>\n  <div class=\"sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32\"><div class=\"sg-col-inner\">\n        \n        <div class=\"a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small\">\n            \n\n\n\n\n<h2 class=\"a-size-mini a-spacing-none a-color-base s-line-clamp-4\">\n    \n    \n        \n\n\n\n\n<a class=\"a-link-normal a-text-normal\" href=\"/Philips-Norelco-Electric-S1560-81/dp/B01859QHJU\">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span class=\"a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal\">Philips Norelco Electric Shaver 2100, S1560/81</span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n\n    \n</h2>\n\n        </div>\n        \n            <div class=\"a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-micro\">\n                <div class=\"a-row a-size-small\">\n\n\n<span aria-label=\"4.1 out of 5 stars\">\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n    \n        <span class=\"a-declarative\" data-action=\"a-popover\" data-a-popover='{\"max-width\":\"700\",\"closeButton\":false,\"position\":\"triggerBottom\",\"url\":\"/review/widgets/average-customer-review/popover/ref=acr_search__popover?ie=UTF8&amp;asin=B01859QHJU&amp;ref=acr_search__popover&amp;contextId=search\"}'>\n            \n            <a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" class=\"a-popover-trigger a-declarative\"><i class=\"a-icon a-icon-star-small a-star-small-4 aok-align-bottom\"><span class=\"a-icon-alt\">4.1 out of 5 stars</span></i><i class=\"a-icon a-icon-popover\"></i></a>\n        </span>\n    \n    \n\n\n</span>\n\n\n\n<span aria-label=\"3,260\">\n    \n\n\n\n\n<a class=\"a-link-normal\" href=\"/Philips-Norelco-Electric-S1560-81/dp/B01859QHJU#customerReviews\">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span class=\"a-size-base\">3,260</span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n\n</span>\n</div>\n            </div>\n        \n  </div></div>\n  <div class=\"sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32\"><div class=\"sg-col-inner\">\n        \n        \n            <div class=\"a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small\">\n                <div class=\"a-row a-size-base a-color-base\"><div class=\"a-row\">\n\n\n\n\n<a class=\"a-size-base a-link-normal s-no-hover a-text-normal\" href=\"/Philips-Norelco-Electric-S1560-81/dp/B01859QHJU\">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span class=\"a-price\" data-a-size=\"l\" data-a-color=\"base\"><span class=\"a-offscreen\">$39.96</span><span aria-hidden=\"true\"><span class=\"a-price-symbol\">$</span><span class=\"a-price-whole\">39<span class=\"a-price-decimal\">.</span></span><span class=\"a-price-fraction\">96</span></span></span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n</div></div>\n            </div>\n        \n        \n            <div class=\"a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-micro\">\n                <div class=\"a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary s-align-children-center\"><div class=\"a-row s-align-children-center\">\n\n\n\n\n<span class=\"aok-inline-block s-image-logo-view\">\n  <span class=\"aok-relative s-icon-text-medium s-prime\">\n    <i class=\"a-icon a-icon-prime a-icon-medium\" role=\"img\" aria-label=\"Amazon Prime\"></i>\n  </span>\n  <span>\n    \n  </span>\n</span>\n\n\n\n<span aria-label=\"Get it as soon as Tomorrow, Jul 11\">\n    <span>Get it as soon as </span><span class=\"a-text-bold\">Tomorrow, Jul 11</span>\n</span>\n</div><div class=\"a-row\">\n\n\n<span aria-label=\"FREE Shipping by Amazon\">\n    <span>FREE Shipping by Amazon</span>\n</span>\n</div></div>\n            </div>\n        \n        \n        \n        \n        \n  </div></div>\n  <div class=\"sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32\"><div class=\"sg-col-inner\">\n        \n  </div></div>\n  <div class=\"sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32\"><div class=\"sg-col-inner\">\n        \n        \n  </div></div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n\n</div></div>",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `:contains("Sponsored")` for testing if the result is ad or not:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from textwrap import shorten

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=shaver+for+men&i=beauty&ref=nb_sb_noss_2'
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'lxml')

print('{: ^55}{: ^12}{: ^13}'.format('Title', 'Price', 'Sponsored_Tag'))
for div in soup.select('div[data-asin]'):
    title, price = div.select_one('span.a-text-normal').text, div.select_one('.a-offscreen').text if div.select_one('.a-offscreen') else '-'
    sponsored = 'Yes' if div.select_one('span:contains("Sponsored")') else 'No'
    print('{: <55}{: ^12}{: ^13}'.format(shorten(title, 55), price, sponsored))
```

Prints:

```
                         Title                            Price    Sponsored_Tag
Braun Series 7 Electric Shaver for Men 7893s, Wet [...]  $169.99        Yes     
Philips Norelco Shaver 4500 (Model AT830/46) [...]        $79.95        Yes     
Philips Norelco Electric Shaver 2100, S1560/81            $39.96        No      
Philips Norelco Multigroom Series 3000, [...]             $19.90        No      
5 In 1 Rechargeable Electric Shaver Razor Men [...]       $34.99        No      
Remington F5-5800 Foil Shaver, Men's Electric [...]       $42.94        No      
Philips Norelco OneBlade hybrid electric trimmer [...]    $34.95        No      
Remington PG6025 All-in-1 Lithium Powered [...]           $19.99        No      
Electric Shaver for Men Waterproof, DynaBliss 3D [...]    $39.96        No      
Panasonic Electric Shaver and Trimmer for Men, [...]      $99.99        No      
Men’s 5-in-1 Electric Shaver & Grooming Kit: [...]        $54.99        No      
Philips Norelco Electric Shaver 8900, Wet & Dry [...]    $149.99        No      
Braun Series 3 ProSkin 3040s Electric Razor for [...]     $69.94        No      
Electric Shaver for Men Wet and Dry Waterproof, [...]     $29.99        No      
Philips Norelco Shaver 4500 (Model AT830/46) [...]        $79.95        No      
Electric Shaver Razor for Men 5 in 1 Rotary [...]         $39.99        No      
MOOSOO M Electric Razor for Men Electric Shaver [...]     $42.99        No      
Panasonic Electric Shaver and Trimmer for Men [...]       $69.99        No      
Wahl Professional 5-Star Series Rechargeable [...]        $79.95        No      
Philips Norelco Multigroom Series 7000, [...]             $54.95        No      
Philips Norelco Electric Shaver 6800, S6880/81, [...]       -           No      
Panasonic Arc5 Electric Razor, Men's 5-Blade [...]          -           No      
SweetLF 3D Rechargeable 100% Waterproof IPX7 [...]        $36.99        No      
Men’s 5-in-1 Electric Shaver & Grooming Kit by [...]      $49.99        No      
Panasonic Hybrid Wet Dry Shaver, Trimmer & [...]          $79.99        No      
Andis 17150 Profoil Lithium                               $50.45        No      
Philips Norelco OneBlade hybrid electric trimmer [...]    $34.95        Yes     
Philips Norelco 9000 Prestige Electric Shaver [...]      $277.49        Yes     
Braun Electric Razor for Men / Electric Shaver, [...]     $49.94        Yes     
Gillette Fusion5 Proglide Men's Razor Handle + 4 [...]    $21.99        Yes     
Electric Razor, Electric Shavers for Men, 4 in 1 [...]    $28.99        No      
Philips Norelco Shaver 4100 (Model AT810/46)              $59.97        No      
Electric Razor for Men,FLYCO Electric Shavers 2 [...]     $24.99        No      
Panasonic Electric Travel Shaver, ES3831K                 $14.65        No      
Electric Razor Shaver for Men, 4 in 1 Dry Wet [...]       $29.99        No      
Braun Series 3 Shave&Style 3010BT 3-in-1 Electric [...]   $59.94        No      
Braun Electric Razor for Men / Electric Shaver, [...]     $49.94        No      
Braun Series 3 310s Electric Razor for Men, [...]         $39.94        No      
Max-Tcare Men's Electric Shaver - Corded and [...]        $37.96        No      
Wahl Speed Shave Rechargeable Lithium Ion Wet/Dry [...]   $32.40        No      
Electric Shaver and Beard Trimmer - 5 in 1 Multi- [...]   $27.98        No      
Panasonic ES-LA63-S Arc4 Men's Electric Razor, [...]     $101.95        No      
Philips Norelco Corded Electric Shaver 1100, [...]        $29.99        No      
INSMART Electric Shaver for men, Waterproof [...]         $33.99        No      
Philips Norelco Electric Shaver 5570 Wet & Dry, [...]    $114.98        No      
HATTEKER Electric Shaver For Men Rotary Shaver [...]      $32.99        No      
Philips Norelco Electric shaver 3100, S3310/81 [...]      $49.95        No      
Dee Banna 5D Wet Dry Electric Rotary Shaver Men's [...]   $24.99        No      
Men’s 5-in-1 Electric Shaver & Grooming Kit Hair [...]    $35.99        No      
(Updated Version) Electric Shaver for Men, [...]          $29.99        No      
MANGROOMER Ultimate Pro Back Shaver with 2 Shock [...]    $49.99        No      
Philips Norelco Bodygroom Series 7000, BG7030/49, [...]   $69.95        No      
Electric Razor for Men 4 in 1 Rotary Shavers [...]        $33.99        No      
Wahl Clipper Stainless Steel Lithium Ion Plus [...]       $59.97        No      
Philips Norelco Electric Shaver 8900, Wet & Dry [...]    $149.99        Yes     
Max-Tcare Men's Electric Shaver - Corded and [...]        $35.96        Yes     
Electric Razor for Men Wet & Dry Cordless Foil [...]      $42.99        Yes     
Electric Shaver for Men Waterproof, DynaBliss 3D [...]    $39.96        Yes     
Panasonic Electric Shaver and Trimmer for Men, [...]      $99.99        Yes     
Men's 5-in-1 Electric Shaver Razor & Grooming Kit [...]   $31.99        Yes
```

Comment: Appreciated! Is there any possibility to get your "Soup" solution into the function in my code (and store the results in the item['test'])?  

def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.css('.s-result-item'):

Comment: @Roverflow I don't know Scrapy but you could try to test if `product.css('span:contains("Sponsored")')` exists... As I said, I don't use Scrapy so maybe it won't work.

Comment: The contains css selector works fine in Scrapy, so your solution should work!

Comment: I tried the script two times, with: 
item['test'] = product.css('span:contains("Sponsored")')

and one with get() behind it, item['test'] = product.css('span:contains("Sponsored")').get()


Unfortunately, the first result was only "test[]" for all the rows, and with the second try it was: "test": null. Any ideas how I can fix this? Again, both, thanks really appreciated!

Comment: @Roverflow I would suggest to debug print what tags `product` contains and see if there's `Sponsored` string.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think it is in my product. But I don't understand that, since if you search for .s-result-item (on the page), you will find the products, and intended the "div data-component-type" where we see /sponsored-products/... (the pattern that I am looking for). I edited the post, with an example of the product.

Comment: Ps. I was not able to get your solution up and running (NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.)

Comment: @Roverflow It seems you are using older version of BeautifulSoup. I'm on version `beautifulsoup4==4.7.1`

Comment: I use your solution, but therefore I need to use rotating (or different) user agents (to avoid detection). Unfortunattely, when I change the headers to: headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'}

Or, when I use Rotating User-agents, I receive this error: 

    title, price = div.select_one('span.a-text-normal').text, div.select_one('.a-offscreen').text if div.select_one('.a-offscreen') else '-'

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Any idea how I can fix this? Many thanks!

Comment: Ps. the same error occurs when I use rotating User-Agents (https://edmundmartin.com/random-user-agent-requests-python/)

Comment: @Roverflow Amazon could have protection against bot based on IP Address, not just User-Agents. With that, you need to use some proxy-service

Comment: Thanks! But I added some extra URLs (changed the code a bit), and some of them are scraped, and others not (while all the url's are correct). In my previous code (scrapy) rotating user-agents did the trick... (in addition, I am using a VPN which I change often).

Do you know if there are possiblities to try to run the code with a different user agent (or best case: rotating user agents)? Many thanks @AndrejKesely

Comment: @Roverflow That's a question not suited for this comment section. It's better to open a new question.

Comment: @AndrejKesely you are right. Thanks anyways for your help! Pure FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57072746/rotating-or-different-user-agent-is-giving-the-error-attributeerror-nonetyp