# Missing information while scraping - possible due a wrong css.selector

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

Currently I am trying some stuff with Scraping (scrapy) in Python, and I cannot solve this (I tried many things, and even raised a question on Stack before, see below the url).

I tried to scrape a two [websites](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=shaver&ref=nb_sb_noss_1) (they are in my script), and I received results. However, I am missing information and I can't find out why.

The scraper works. But I can not scrape the '[Sponsored Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56965738/scrape-a-tag-from-amazon/56967686?noredirect=1#comment100504447_56967686)' (in the code see part: item['Sponsored_Tag'] ).

**My question: How can I get the results, as I have now, but including the sponsored tag?**

**What have I tried?**
I tried multiple things. Such as, changing the response.css() (into 's-result-list s-search-results) for example.

And I thought, that I had the solution. If you look on one of the pages, you can see (if you search for "s-result-item", which is our response.css) that the results contain a text, called "AdHolder". But, I couldn't find it back in my scraped results... (See picture below)

[image: PrintScreen of the s-result-item. You see that there is something which is called AdHolder...]

**Desired outcome**

A file (currently, I am writing a JSON file), with this information:

```
 - Sponsored Tag: Yes/No           **#This is what is missing!**
 - ASIN: XXXXXXXX                  #This works in the code below
 - Index: "0"                      #This works in the code below 
 - Link: "complete link"           #This works in the code below 
 - url_response: "response link"   #This works in the code below
 - tag: Bestsellertag etc.         #This works in the code below
```

**My Code:**

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
#import re

class AmazonProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "AmazonDeals"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]

    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,}
    #Use working product URL below
    start_urls = [
            "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=shaver&ref=nb_sb_noss_1",          # Shaver
            "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=electric+shaver&ref=nb_sb_noss_2"]#

custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI' : 'Asin_Titles.json',
        'FEED_FORMAT' : 'json'
        }

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.css('.s-result-item'):   # Do I scrape the wrong information? 
            item = AmazonItem()

            # I think that this part goes wrong (the item['Sponsored_Tag'] part)
            item['Sponsored_Tag'] = product.css('span:contains("Sponsored")') 
            #item['Sponsored_Tag'] = product.css('.s-result-item').get() #.css('contains("sponsored")').get()

            item['Prime_tag'] = product.css('.a-color-secondary').get()
            item['asin'] = product.css('::attr(data-asin)').get()
            item['index'] = product.css('::attr(data-index)').get()
            item['link'] = product.css('.a-text-normal::attr(href)').get() 
            item['url_Response'] = response.url
            item['tag'] = product.css('.a-badge-text').get()
            yield item

class AmazonItem(scrapy.Item):
    asin = scrapy.Field()
    index = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    url_Response = scrapy.Field()
    tag = scrapy.Field()
    Prime_tag = scrapy.Field() 
    Sponsored_Tag = scrapy.Field()
```

**EDIT 1**

Solution, as mentioned by ThePyGuy, integrated. Unfortunately, all results (of the 'adHolder' item are NULL.

```
    def parse(self, response):
    item = AmazonItem()

    for result in response.css('.s-result-list div'):
        if result.css('.AdHolder').extract_first():
            item['adholder'] = True
        else:
            item['adholder'] = False

    for product in response.css('.s-result-item'):    #.s-result-item 
        #item = AmazonItem()
        #item['Sponsored_Tag'] = product.css('span:contains("sponsored")').get()
        #item['Sponsored_Tag'] = product.css('.s-result-item').get() #.css('contains("sponsored")').get()

        item['Prime_tag'] = product.css('.a-color-secondary').get()
        item['asin'] = product.css('::attr(data-asin)').get()
        item['index'] = product.css('::attr(data-index)').get()
        item['link'] = product.css('.a-text-normal::attr(href)').get() 
        item['url_Response'] = response.url
        item['tag'] = product.css('.a-badge-text').get()
        # And so on 
        # ...
        yield item

class AmazonItem(scrapy.Item):   
asin = scrapy.Field()
index = scrapy.Field()
link = scrapy.Field()
url_Response = scrapy.Field()
tag = scrapy.Field()
Prime_tag = scrapy.Field() 
#Sponsored_Tag = scrapy.Field()
adholder = scrapy.Field()
```

**Edit 2**

As mentioned by ThePyGuy, everything in one loop. Two issues here:

1. AdHolder (or the sponsored tag) is not scraped (everything is FALSE, which is impossible).
2. We have now too many products +/- 3095, while I was expecting around the (two pages, 40/50 products = 80/100 products)

   ```
   def parse(self, response):

   for result in response.css('.s-result-list div'):
       item = AmazonItem()

       if result.css('.AdHolder').extract_first():
           item['adholder'] = True
       else:
           item['adholder'] = False

       item['Prime_tag'] = result.css('.a-color-secondary').get()
       item['asin'] = result.css('::attr(data-asin)').get()
       item['index'] = result.css('::attr(data-index)').get()
       item['link'] = result.css('.a-text-normal::attr(href)').get() 
       item['url_Response'] = response.url
       item['tag'] = result.css('.a-badge-text').get()
       # And so on 
       # ...
       yield item
   ```

In advance, many thanks for helping.

Comment: I want to ask if you are using Crawlera? If so are you experiencing extremely slow crawls right now for Amazon urls?

PS: Check your response in console and be sure you're served the sponsored tag. Lots of times these ads and such are served up via JavaScript.

Comment: Things like ads are often loaded either async or inserted with a delay. It is possible that your scraper did not wait long enough to get the data. Try adding some arbitrary time out o your script, and ensure that JavaScript is executed.

Comment: @ThePyGuy thanks! I am not using Crawlera... I know that it is possible to scrape them, but I cannot make the whole integration (see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56965738/scrape-a-tag-from-amazon/56967686?noredirect=1#comment100504447_56967686)

Comment: @BramVanroy thanks. I will test with adding some time.sleep() in the code. Is it smart place that statement after " for product in response.css('.s-result-item'):"? 

In addition, I know that it is possible to scrape that (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56965738/scrape-a-tag-from-amazon/56967686?noredirect=1#comment100504447_56967686). Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
In [4]: print(response.css('.s-result-list .AdHolder').extract())                                                                                                                                                                                                              
['<div data-asin="B07F7XYMNN" data-index="0" class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 s-result-item sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 AdHolder sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n    \n\n\n<div data-component-type="s-impression-logger" data-component-props=\'{"percentageShownToFire":"50","batchable":true,"requiredElementSelector":".s-image","url":"https://www.amazon.com/gp/sponsored-products/logging/log-action.html?qualifier=1563148367&amp;id=6965017493400297&amp;widgetName=sp_atf&amp;adId=200011353751711&amp;eventType=1&amp;adIndex=0"}\' class="rush-component s-expand-height">\n    \n\n\n<div data-component-type="sp-sponsored-result" class="rush-component s-expand-height">\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<div class="s-expand-height s-include-content-margin s-border-bottom">\n<div class="a-section a-spacing-medium">\n\n\n<div class="sg-row">\n  <div class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n        <div class="a-section a-spacing-micro s-min-height-extra-large">\n            \n        </div>\n    </div></div>\n</div>\n\n<div class="sg-row">\n  <div class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n        \n        <div class="a-section a-spacing-none">\n            \n\n\n\n\n\n<span data-component-type="s-product-image" class="rush-component">\n    \n    <a class="a-link-normal" href="/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&amp;adId=A0414635KJLKI9OVJ7G1&amp;url=%2FBraun-Electric-Integrated-Precision-Rechargeable%2Fdp%2FB07F7XYMNN%2Fref%3Dsr_1_1_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dshaver%26qid%3D1563148367%26s%3Dgateway%26sr%3D8-1-spons%26psc%3D1&amp;qualifier=1563148367&amp;id=6965017493400297&amp;widgetName=sp_atf">\n        <div class="a-section aok-relative s-image-square-aspect">\n            \n                \n                \n                    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81Y8IzpMY2L._AC_UL320_.jpg" class="s-image" alt="Braun Series 9 Men\'s Electric Foil Shaver with Wet &amp; Dry Integrated Precision Trimmer &amp; Rechargeable and Cordless Razor with Clean&amp;Charge Station, 9296cc" srcset="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81Y8IzpMY2L._AC_UL320_.jpg 1x, https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81Y8IzpMY2L._AC_UL480_QL65_.jpg 1.5x, https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81Y8IzpMY2L._AC_UL640_QL65_.jpg 2x, https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81Y8IzpMY2L._AC_UL800_QL65_.jpg 2.5x, https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81Y8IzpMY2L._AC_UL960_QL65_.jpg 3x" data-image-index="0" data-image-load="" data-image-latency="s-product-image" data-image-source-density="1">\n                \n            \n        </div>\n    </a>\n</span>\n\n        </div>\n        \n  </div></div>\n  <div class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n        \n        <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small">\n            <div class="a-row a-spacing-micro"><span class="a-size-base a-color-secondary">Sponsored</span>\n\n\n\n\n\n<span class="a-declarative" data-action="a-popover" data-a-popover=\'{"dataStrategy":"preload","name":"sp-info-popover-B07F7XYMNN","position":"triggerVertical"}\'>\n    \n        \n        \n            \n            <span class="aok-inline-block s-info-icon"></span>\n        \n        \n    \n</span>\n\n\n\n    <div class="a-popover-preload" id="a-popover-sp-info-popover-B07F7XYMNN">\n        <span>These are ads for products you\'ll find on Amazon.com. </span><div class="a-row"><span>Clicking an ad will take you to the product\'s page.</span>\n\n\n\n\n<a class="a-link-normal" href="https://advertising.amazon.com/products-self-serve?ref_=ext_amzn_wtsp">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span>Learn more about Sponsored Products.</span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n</div><div class="a-row a-spacing-top-small"><span></span>\n\n\n\n\n\n<span class="a-declarative" data-action="a-modal" data-a-modal=\'{"dataStrategy":"ajax","header":"Share your feedback","url":"/gp/sponsored-products/lazyLoad/handler/sp-feedback-handler.html?pl=lB0mnfW%2BgTIwXZ6x6%2FEkofSU5xhfxxnnc785QXRwbCnTJ%2BJA6GNDd0mNO0LWBiOz0%2BPUMqC%2BfpmF%0Amq1O8nxbZonbXZAJRS9av%2BV16idXdoOcIz11gXk310EIW6PcOMYdRA%2Bp7Z%2FEeOGfKzIeFtB9qQvN%0AjDcmdjwVXrg9HYDbd1wHIPKQtdWBZdOar0OZInRL0%2F7pFW12O6KO3SMD%2B1v35y5myOGZmF51DLTd%0Ar0Eot11Sc8HtuVRMXgD1s8WIwu%2F0zt6zF3tg3EMcdWFtwMCECLKa2xwQfYLDM6NKIeQvOsky9j19%0A0mXHU7i%2FXQ9fL70%2Bf7m0aTvN8LwIHzdNZM6f6qiuarbVWcVp%2B1BM7Q0NyT33bHOLdwKR7DmhKH03%0AjWCKWNQnpeVaWAm%2BuwDwrOBtCI4voFa%2BK4IX5hBAzvyzgBCtATDpdIllsxGZj7dvvaFrkCdPE7w%2B%0AZ%2BzM8Bhfm4SU3nL%2FTRgbAEwM1b%2BMMAW3uFvcDWFHmWmwwTkce6uiLD5d83valaN%2FEgY03Xx0DsSd%0AROuQ8XS7DCpmy7rFmNXOEFSlWSOBf68IZKQniiJid90PjI9TySMEuuA%3D"}\'>\n    \n        \n        \n        \n            \n\n\n\n\n<a class="a-link-normal" href="#">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span></span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n\n        \n    \n</span>\n\n\n\n</div>\n    </div>\n\n</div>\n\n\n\n\n<h2 class="a-size-mini a-spacing-none a-color-base s-line-clamp-4">\n    \n    \n        \n\n\n\n\n<a class="a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&amp;adId=A0414635KJLKI9OVJ7G1&amp;url=%2FBraun-Electric-Integrated-Precision-Rechargeable%2Fdp%2FB07F7XYMNN%2Fref%3Dsr_1_1_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dshaver%26qid%3D1563148367%26s%3Dgateway%26sr%3D8-1-spons%26psc%3D1&amp;qualifier=1563148367&amp;id=6965017493400297&amp;widgetName=sp_atf">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span class="a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal">Braun Series 9 Men\'s Electric Foil Shaver with Wet &amp; Dry Integrated Precision Trimmer &amp; Rechargeable and Cordless Razor with Clean&amp;Charge Station, 9296cc</span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n\n    \n</h2>\n\n        </div>\n        \n            <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-micro">\n                <div class="a-row a-size-small">\n\n\n<span aria-label="4.4 out of 5 stars">\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n    \n        <span class="a-declarative" data-action="a-popover" data-a-popover=\'{"max-width":"700","closeButton":false,"position":"triggerBottom","url":"/review/widgets/average-customer-review/popover/ref=acr_search__popover?ie=UTF8&amp;asin=B07F7XYMNN&amp;ref=acr_search__popover&amp;contextId=search"}\'>\n            \n            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="a-popover-trigger a-declarative"><i class="a-icon a-icon-star-small a-star-small-4-5 aok-align-bottom"><span class="a-icon-alt">4.4 out of 5 stars</span></i><i class="a-icon a-icon-popover"></i></a>\n        </span>\n    \n    \n\n\n</span>\n\n\n\n<span aria-label="89">\n    \n\n\n\n\n<a class="a-link-normal" href="/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&amp;adId=A0414635KJLKI9OVJ7G1&amp;url=%2FBraun-Electric-Integrated-Precision-Rechargeable%2Fdp%2FB07F7XYMNN%2Fref%3Dsr_1_1_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dshaver%26qid%3D1563148367%26s%3Dgateway%26sr%3D8-1-spons%26psc%3D1&amp;qualifier=1563148367&amp;id=6965017493400297&amp;widgetName=sp_atf#customerReviews">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span class="a-size-base">89</span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n\n</span>\n</div>\n            </div>\n        \n  </div></div>\n  <div class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n        \n        \n            <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small">\n                <div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-base"><div class="a-row">\n\n\n\n\n<a class="a-size-base a-link-normal s-no-hover a-text-normal" href="/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&amp;adId=A0414635KJLKI9OVJ7G1&amp;url=%2FBraun-Electric-Integrated-Precision-Rechargeable%2Fdp%2FB07F7XYMNN%2Fref%3Dsr_1_1_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dshaver%26qid%3D1563148367%26s%3Dgateway%26sr%3D8-1-spons%26psc%3D1&amp;qualifier=1563148367&amp;id=6965017493400297&amp;widgetName=sp_atf">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span class="a-price" data-a-size="l" data-a-color="base"><span class="a-offscreen">$309.99</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">$</span><span class="a-price-whole">309<span class="a-price-decimal">.</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">99</span></span></span>\n            \n                <span class="a-size-base a-color-secondary">($146.91/Pound)</span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n</div></div>\n            </div>\n        \n        \n            <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-micro">\n                <div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary s-align-children-center"><div class="a-row s-align-children-center">\n\n\n\n\n<span class="aok-inline-block s-image-logo-view">\n  <span class="aok-relative s-icon-text-medium s-prime">\n    <i class="a-icon a-icon-prime a-icon-medium" role="img" aria-label="Amazon Prime"></i>\n  </span>\n  <span>\n    \n  </span>\n</span>\n\n\n\n<span aria-label="Get it as soon as Thu, Jul 18">\n    <span>Get it as soon as </span><span class="a-text-bold">Thu, Jul 18</span>\n</span>\n</div><div class="a-row">\n\n\n<span aria-label="FREE Shipping by Amazon">\n    <span>FREE Shipping by Amazon</span>\n</span>\n</div></div>\n            </div>\n        \n        \n        \n        \n        \n  </div></div>\n  <div class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n        \n  </div></div>\n  <div class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n        \n        \n  </div></div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n\n</div>\n\n</div>\n\n</div></div>', '<div data-asin="B003YJAZZ4" data-index="1" class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 s-result-item sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 AdHolder sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n    \n\n\n<div data-component-type="s-impression-logger" data-component-props=\'{"percentageShownToFire":"50","batchable":true,"requiredElementSelector":".s-image","url":"https://www.amazon.com/gp/sponsored-products/logging/log-action.html?qualifier=1563148367&amp;id=6965017493400297&amp;widgetName=sp_atf&amp;adId=200005657625311&amp;eventType=1&amp;adIndex=1"}\' class="rush-component s-expand-height">\n    \n\n\n<div data-component-type="sp-sponsored-result" class="rush-component s-expand-height">\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<div class="s-expand-height s-include-content-margin s-border-bottom">\n<div class="a-section a-spacing-medium">\n\n\n<div class="sg-row">\n  <div class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n        <div class="a-section a-spacing-micro s-min-height-extra-large">\n            \n        </div>\n    </div></div>\n</div>\n\n<div class="sg-row">\n  <div class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n        \n        <div class="a-section a-spacing-none">\n            \n\n\n\n\n\n<span data-component-type="s-product-image" class="rush-component">\n    \n    <a class="a-link-normal" href="/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_aps_sr_pg1_2?ie=UTF8&amp;adId=A05912003D82ZR77VHH5H&amp;url=%2FBraun-Electric-Shaver-Station-Cordless%2Fdp%2FB003YJAZZ4%2Fref%3Dsr_1_2_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dshaver%26qid%3D1563148367%26s%3Dgateway%26sr%3D8-2-spons%26psc%3D1&amp;qualifier=1563148367&amp;id=6965017493400297&amp;widgetName=sp_atf">\n        <div class="a-section aok-relative s-image-square-aspect">\n            \n                \n                \n                    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/814fSnCl0eL._AC_UL320_.jpg" class="s-image" alt="Braun Series 7 790cc-4 Electric Foil Shaver with Clean&amp;Charge Station, 1 Count" srcset="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/814fSnCl0eL._AC_UL320_.jpg 1x, https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/814fSnCl0eL._AC_UL480_QL65_.jpg 1.5x, https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/814fSnCl0eL._AC_UL640_QL65_.jpg 2x, https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/814fSnCl0eL._AC_UL800_QL65_.jpg 2.5x, https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/814fSnCl0eL._AC_UL960_QL65_.jpg 3x" data-image-index="1" data-image-load="" data-image-latency="s-product-image" data-image-source-density="1">\n                \n            \n        </div>\n    </a>\n</span>\n\n        </div>\n        \n  </div></div>\n  <div class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n        \n        <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small">\n            <div class="a-row a-spacing-micro"><span class="a-size-base a-color-secondary">Sponsored</span>\n\n\n\n\n\n<span class="a-declarative" data-action="a-popover" data-a-popover=\'{"dataStrategy":"preload","name":"sp-info-popover-B003YJAZZ4","position":"triggerVertical"}\'>\n    \n        \n        \n            \n            <span class="aok-inline-block s-info-icon"></span>\n        \n        \n    \n</span>\n\n\n\n    <div class="a-popover-preload" id="a-popover-sp-info-popover-B003YJAZZ4">\n        <span>These are ads for products you\'ll find on Amazon.com. </span><div class="a-row"><span>Clicking an ad will take you to the product\'s page.</span>\n\n\n\n\n<a class="a-link-normal" href="https://advertising.amazon.com/products-self-serve?ref_=ext_amzn_wtsp">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span>Learn more about Sponsored Products.</span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n</div><div class="a-row a-spacing-top-small"><span></span>\n\n\n\n\n\n<span class="a-declarative" data-action="a-modal" data-a-modal=\'{"dataStrategy":"ajax","header":"Share your feedback","url":"/gp/sponsored-products/lazyLoad/handler/sp-feedback-handler.html?pl=KHcYnXwozHREynoNEPM3bbMnH%2FMI8s5SVP9nZyO9%2Bemx9E7m9uWGEQS3nBvHj%2BTpHlWCgtJxv65B%0A1fbbCIAb1ivlHLGe9bDi9XBrklhROSKeoWM3PpYPqCIFGwSusBYKhsKTSsijnU0hcE2kwEkX6dPm%0AYWYhITYXNoUJuWjUPV%2F%2F6IRqxkNKhbsOVZQoki56dZeC6ojhq78vV%2FZUUtSmf8LwehZjTMvF65xc%0A6jxI8nbjFJMvluPsl7BEX7ZfF08o13Ip%2BIY8y8%2BwZMH5SFcUbkqfJtQPYfy3WMrC3fT4zOAu3z5J%0AJau%2BZWLYs7GHgJnQj%2Ftw4VVjQjWJXdund5ND1rLuRP%2B5UnCqff0wXM%2BYZWrAdJKeLpWSavRDwfM2%0AIaPiuHxMS4F%2F0Y05HmeJp%2FPwPWN8YmGMKMoA4egrr2HhF8Yi9dIQLgWLgd%2FNM521RQprNbGbROEU%0ANuWR3XcKd53kwCC2WSt6ZQ5C8SuEjfhdDUxKtA9E4E%2FoKwyvW4OdOVBn1gS8o3cxME8l4IYhL23o%0AW4Z6tYRWSPdXW%2BvflMnJVqE%3D"}\'>\n    \n        \n        \n        \n            \n\n\n\n\n<a class="a-link-normal" href="#">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span></span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n\n        \n    \n</span>\n\n\n\n</div>\n    </div>\n\n</div>\n\n\n\n\n<h2 class="a-size-mini a-spacing-none a-color-base s-line-clamp-4">\n    \n    \n        \n\n\n\n\n<a class="a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_aps_sr_pg1_2?ie=UTF8&amp;adId=A05912003D82ZR77VHH5H&amp;url=%2FBraun-Electric-Shaver-Station-Cordless%2Fdp%2FB003YJAZZ4%2Fref%3Dsr_1_2_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dshaver%26qid%3D1563148367%26s%3Dgateway%26sr%3D8-2-spons%26psc%3D1&amp;qualifier=1563148367&amp;id=6965017493400297&amp;widgetName=sp_atf">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span class="a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal">Braun Series 7 790cc-4 Electric Foil Shaver with Clean&amp;Charge Station, 1 Count</span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n\n    \n</h2>\n\n        </div>\n        \n            <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-micro">\n                <div class="a-row a-size-small">\n\n\n<span aria-label="4.3 out of 5 stars">\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n    \n        <span class="a-declarative" data-action="a-popover" data-a-popover=\'{"max-width":"700","closeButton":false,"position":"triggerBottom","url":"/review/widgets/average-customer-review/popover/ref=acr_search__popover?ie=UTF8&amp;asin=B003YJAZZ4&amp;ref=acr_search__popover&amp;contextId=search"}\'>\n            \n            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="a-popover-trigger a-declarative"><i class="a-icon a-icon-star-small a-star-small-4-5 aok-align-bottom"><span class="a-icon-alt">4.3 out of 5 stars</span></i><i class="a-icon a-icon-popover"></i></a>\n        </span>\n    \n    \n\n\n</span>\n\n\n\n<span aria-label="7,761">\n    \n\n\n\n\n<a class="a-link-normal" href="/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_aps_sr_pg1_2?ie=UTF8&amp;adId=A05912003D82ZR77VHH5H&amp;url=%2FBraun-Electric-Shaver-Station-Cordless%2Fdp%2FB003YJAZZ4%2Fref%3Dsr_1_2_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dshaver%26qid%3D1563148367%26s%3Dgateway%26sr%3D8-2-spons%26psc%3D1&amp;qualifier=1563148367&amp;id=6965017493400297&amp;widgetName=sp_atf#customerReviews">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span class="a-size-base">7,761</span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n\n</span>\n</div>\n            </div>\n        \n  </div></div>\n  <div class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n        \n        \n            <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small">\n                <div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-base"><div class="a-row">\n\n\n\n\n<a class="a-size-base a-link-normal s-no-hover a-text-normal" href="/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_aps_sr_pg1_2?ie=UTF8&amp;adId=A05912003D82ZR77VHH5H&amp;url=%2FBraun-Electric-Shaver-Station-Cordless%2Fdp%2FB003YJAZZ4%2Fref%3Dsr_1_2_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dshaver%26qid%3D1563148367%26s%3Dgateway%26sr%3D8-2-spons%26psc%3D1&amp;qualifier=1563148367&amp;id=6965017493400297&amp;widgetName=sp_atf">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span class="a-price" data-a-size="l" data-a-color="base"><span class="a-offscreen">$199.94</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">$</span><span class="a-price-whole">199<span class="a-price-decimal">.</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">94</span></span></span>\n            \n                <span class="a-price" data-a-size="b" data-a-strike="true" data-a-color="secondary"><span class="a-offscreen">$289.99</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">$</span><span class="a-price-whole">289<span class="a-price-decimal">.</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">99</span></span></span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n</div></div><div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary"><div class="a-row">\n\n\n\n\n\n<span data-component-type="s-coupon-component" data-component-props=\'{"asin":"B003YJAZZ4"}\' class="rush-component">\n    <span class="s-coupon-clipped aok-hidden">\n        <span class="a-color-base">$20.00 coupon applied.</span>\n    </span>\n    <span class="s-coupon-unclipped ">\n        \n\n\n<span class="a-size-base s-coupon-highlight-color s-highlighted-text-padding aok-inline-block">\n    Save $20.00\n</span>\n\n        <span class="a-color-base"> with coupon</span>\n    </span>\n    \n</span>\n</div></div>\n            </div>\n        \n        \n            <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-micro">\n                <div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary s-align-children-center"><div class="a-row s-align-children-center">\n\n\n\n\n<span class="aok-inline-block s-image-logo-view">\n  <span class="aok-relative s-icon-text-medium s-prime">\n    <i class="a-icon a-icon-prime a-icon-medium" role="img" aria-label="Amazon Prime"></i>\n  </span>\n  <span>\n    \n  </span>\n</span>\n\n\n\n<span aria-label="Get it as soon as Thu, Jul 18">\n    <span>Get it as soon as </span><span class="a-text-bold">Thu, Jul 18</span>\n</span>\n</div><div class="a-row">\n\n\n<span aria-label="FREE Shipping by Amazon">\n    <span>FREE Shipping by Amazon</span>\n</span>\n</div></div>\n            </div>\n        \n        \n        \n        \n        \n  </div></div>\n  <div class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n        \n  </div></div>\n  <div class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n        \n        \n  </div></div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n\n</div>\n\n</div>\n\n</div></div>', '<div data-asin="B01M716CC2" data-index="19" class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 s-result-item sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 AdHolder sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n    \n\n\n<div data-component-type="s-impression-logger" data-component-props=\'{"percentageShownToFire":"50","batchable":true,"requiredElementSelector":".s-image","url":"https://www.amazon.com/gp/sponsored-products/logging/log-action.html?qualifier=1563148367&amp;id=6965017493400297&amp;widgetName=sp_mtf&amp;adId=200003291706211&amp;eventType=1&amp;adIndex=2"}\' class="rush-component s-expand-height">\n    \n\n\n<div data-component-type="sp-sponsored-result" class="rush-component s-expand-height">\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<div class="s-expand-height s-include-content-margin s-border-bottom">\n<div class="a-section a-spacing-medium">\n\n\n<div class="sg-row">\n  <div class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n        <div class="a-section a-spacing-micro s-min-height-extra-large">\n            \n        </div>\n    </div></div>\n</div>\n\n<div class="sg-row">\n  <div class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n        \n        <div class="a-section a-spacing-none">\n            \n\n\n\n\n\n<span data-component-type="s-product-image" class="rush-component">\n    \n    <a class="a-link-normal" href="/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_mtf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&amp;adId=A0238051Q7V9JY6EMHYF&amp;url=%2FBraun-Electric-Shaver-9290cc-Travel%2Fdp%2FB01M716CC2%2Fref%3Dsr_1_19_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dshaver%26qid%3D1563148367%26s%3Dgateway%26sr%3D8-19-spons%26psc%3D1&amp;qualifier=1563148367&amp;id=6965017493400297&amp;widgetName=sp_mtf">\n        <div class="a-section aok-relative s-image-square-aspect">\n            \n                \n                \n                    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81CmsUO2IzL._AC_UL320_.jpg" class="s-image" alt="Braun Series 9 9290cc Electric Razor for Men, Rechargeable and Cordless Electric Shaver, Foil Shaver, Silver, with Clean&amp;Charge Station and Travel Case" srcset="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81CmsUO2IzL._AC_UL320_.jpg 1x, https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81CmsUO2IzL._AC_UL480_QL65_.jpg 1.5x, https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81CmsUO2IzL._AC_UL640_QL65_.jpg 2x, https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81CmsUO2IzL._AC_UL800_QL65_.jpg 2.5x, https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81CmsUO2IzL._AC_UL960_QL65_.jpg 3x" data-image-index="19" data-image-load="" data-image-latency="s-product-image" data-image-source-density="1">\n                \n            \n        </div>\n    </a>\n</span>\n\n        </div>\n        \n  </div></div>\n  <div class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n        \n        <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small">\n            <div class="a-row a-spacing-micro"><span class="a-size-base a-color-secondary">Sponsored</span>\n\n\n\n\n\n<span class="a-declarative" data-action="a-popover" data-a-popover=\'{"dataStrategy":"preload","name":"sp-info-popover-B01M716CC2","position":"triggerVertical"}\'>\n    \n        \n        \n            \n            <span class="aok-inline-block s-info-icon"></span>\n        \n        \n    \n</span>\n\n\n\n    <div class="a-popover-preload" id="a-popover-sp-info-popover-B01M716CC2">\n        <span>These are ads for products you\'ll find on Amazon.com. </span><div class="a-row"><span>Clicking an ad will take you to the product\'s page.</span>\n\n\n\n\n<a class="a-link-normal" href="https://advertising.amazon.com/products-self-serve?ref_=ext_amzn_wtsp">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span>Learn more about Sponsored Products.</span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n</div><div class="a-row a-spacing-top-small"><span></span>\n\n\n\n\n\n<span class="a-declarative" data-action="a-modal" data-a-modal=\'{"dataStrategy":"ajax","header":"Share your feedback","url":"/gp/sponsored-products/lazyLoad/handler/sp-feedback-handler.html?pl=0p%2BGEEYfSi3REr7K6Ac9Nqe9JjlS1kupaJ7MTBFbv7xen2TPg5Oc%2BN2Ae163fnU01qKZeDgPtGas%0A0Feh9ykvFdqBAZMnMfCHs4k%2Beht6HW%2FzanzhIRMebuDSFcmpXsxMIlEyihB6RIC2LnQNUhfy8i3x%0AWhSijAPnRknldtvl%2BiXb%2FomJhnuVZuVr0qxvvFXe4cjEudG1ABX946GnadxoboiHHfy9GwF6QF1b%0ATdmSjB%2BE7yy3HB3B6E9ImtbgoqBIk4aSkqRyXuahRoAp1brZO3Nn3qFPYXDIG2%2F%2BCDzJndYLL%2FCK%0AVvZ3R6lN42KA6oTI4CxoMs%2FmfiN7P85KWyTeS8YX6ICcjkaIjnvxjOCDp%2FX8%2FDrKYNWc8GrdY4Fb%0ABQSlas58beh5VfDSQ0Tiwe3TkLoIXzEGFfsIPEa2OP0AyJWut4dsSB%2FQ%2FHzx71c27lH0R6cIGGdV%0APA0iOLrWXAYZpM6VBSEcKJb4Zu%2F0bnzB%2Be6s9yF%2FduaUtfqsiXgXyypf3TA1wNADbj0mPJp1Fj5W%0AEdvQxCk8Z%2B6fIpGfW%2Bh6d%2BI4PP3QDZF6yjN5%2FFd1jf8O%2BXp5AefGs38%3D"}\'>\n    \n        \n        \n        \n            \n\n\n\n\n<a class="a-link-normal" href="#">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span></span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n\n        \n    \n</span>\n\n\n\n</div>\n    </div>\n\n</div>\n\n\n\n\n<h2 class="a-size-mini a-spacing-none a-color-base s-line-clamp-4">\n    \n    \n        \n\n\n\n\n<a class="a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_mtf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&amp;adId=A0238051Q7V9JY6EMHYF&amp;url=%2FBraun-Electric-Shaver-9290cc-Travel%2Fdp%2FB01M716CC2%2Fref%3Dsr_1_19_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dshaver%26qid%3D1563148367%26s%3Dgateway%26sr%3D8-19-spons%26psc%3D1&amp;qualifier=1563148367&amp;id=6965017493400297&amp;widgetName=sp_mtf">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span class="a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal">Braun Series 9 9290cc Electric Razor for Men, Rechargeable and Cordless Electric Shaver, Foil Shaver, Silver, with Clean&amp;Charge Station and Travel Case</span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n\n    \n</h2>\n\n        </div>\n        \n            <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-micro">\n                <div class="a-row a-size-small">\n\n\n<span aria-label="3.9 out of 5 stars">\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n    \n        <span class="a-declarative" data-action="a-popover" data-a-popover=\'{"max-width":"700","closeButton":false,"position":"triggerBottom","url":"/review/widgets/average-customer-review/popover/ref=acr_search__popover?ie=UTF8&amp;asin=B01M716CC2&amp;ref=acr_search__popover&amp;contextId=search"}\'>\n            \n            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="a-popover-trigger a-declarative"><i class="a-icon a-icon-star-small a-star-small-4 aok-align-bottom"><span class="a-icon-alt">3.9 out of 5 stars</span></i><i class="a-icon a-icon-popover"></i></a>\n        </span>\n    \n    \n\n\n</span>\n\n\n\n<span aria-label="1,079">\n    \n\n\n\n\n<a class="a-link-normal" href="/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_mtf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&amp;adId=A0238051Q7V9JY6EMHYF&amp;url=%2FBraun-Electric-Shaver-9290cc-Travel%2Fdp%2FB01M716CC2%2Fref%3Dsr_1_19_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dshaver%26qid%3D1563148367%26s%3Dgateway%26sr%3D8-19-spons%26psc%3D1&amp;qualifier=1563148367&amp;id=6965017493400297&amp;widgetName=sp_mtf#customerReviews">\n    \n        \n            \n                <span class="a-size-base">1,079</span>\n            \n        \n        \n    \n</a>\n\n</span>\n</div>\n            </div>\n        \n  </div></div>\n  <div class="sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32"><div class="sg-col-inner">\n        \n        \n            <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small">\n                <div class="a-row a-size-base a-color-base"><div class="a-row">\n\n\n\n\n<a class="a-size-base a-link-normal s-no-hover a-text-normal" href="/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_mtf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&amp;adId=A0238051Q7V9JY6EMHYF&amp;url=%2FBraun-Electric-Shaver-9290cc-Travel%2Fdp%2FB01M716CC2%2Fref%3Dsr_1_19_sspa%3Fkeywords%3Dshaver%26qid%3D1563148367%26s%3Dgateway%26sr%3D8-19-spons%26psc%3D1&amp;
```

To expand on this you would probably want to do something like:

```
for result in response.css('.s-result-list div'):
    if result.css('.AdHolder').extract_first():
        item['adholder'] = True
    else:
        item['adholder'] = False
    rest of item logic
```

I'm not exactly happy with this way of things but I think it will work.

Comment: Thanks @ThePyGuy. I added your solution in my post, but unfortunately, all the results are NULL (which is impossible, seen the real results on the page). Did I integrate it well? Many thanks!

Comment: Do it all in one loop. Take out your second for loop and set your items with result.css and see if that works. It will step through each first div in the result list, check if its an add holder and set appropriately. Hopefully anyways.

Comment: Appreciated! I updated my code (see question, Edit 2), but unfortunately it is not giving the results: 1). All results are FALSE, 2). we have now way too many results (around the 3.000 instead of 80-100). Am I building your idea correctly? Of did I do something wrong?

Comment: Yes it looks more correct...The divs show up in my console when i look for them. Maybe they are not showing up in the main list for some reason. Are the first two listings always sponsored?

Comment: Yes, in the two URL's, the two first ones (data-index = 0 & data-index = 1) are always sponsored. 

Can you share your code? Is it exactly the same as I posted in Edit 2? Thanks!!