# Rotating (or different) User-Agent is giving the Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'am trying to scrape some information from the web. But unfortunately, I need to change my user-agents (ideally rotating them). I found some solutions and integrated them into my script.

But, that resulted into a error message:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

My question, What goes wrong and how can I use rotating user agents in my script? (see #Error in the script)

Example:

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

urls = ["https://www.amazon.com/s?k=shaver&ref=nb_sb_noss_1",    
        "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=electric+shaver&ref=nb_sb_noss_2", 
        "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=electric+razor&ref=nb_sb_noss_2"]

#headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'}  #ERROR

#headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'} #ERROR

headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'} #Works

df = pd.DataFrame(columns =['Title', 'Price', 'Sponsored','url', 'asin', 'index_asin'])

for url in urls:
    print('URL',url)
    sleep(randint(10,15))
    response = requests.get(url)

    print('Response ')
    print(response)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers= headers).text, 'lxml') #lxml

    for div in soup.select('div[data-asin]'):
        title, price = div.select_one('span.a-text-normal').text, div.select_one('.a-offscreen').text if div.select_one('.a-offscreen') else '-'
        sponsored = 'Yes' if div.select_one('span:contains("Sponsored")') else 'No'
        url = response.url
        asin = div['data-asin']
        try:
          index_asin = div['data-index']
        except:
          index_asin='NAN'
        print('title', title)

        #print('title',title)
        #print('price',price)
        #print('sponsored',sponsored)
        #print('url',url)
        #print('asin',asin)
        #print('index_asin',index_asin)

        # I want to store everything in a data frame
        df=df.append({'Title':title,'Price':price,'Sponsored':sponsored,'url':url,'asin':asin,'index_asin':index_asin},ignore_index=True)
```

**Edit, as requested the full error**

When I run this script: (note that I used a different 'headers' variable, see #Error and #Works)

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

urls = ["https://www.amazon.com/s?k=shaver&ref=nb_sb_noss_1",    
        "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=electric+shaver&ref=nb_sb_noss_2", 
        "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=electric+razor&ref=nb_sb_noss_2"]

#headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'}  #ERROR

headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'} #ERROR

#headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'} #Works

df = pd.DataFrame(columns =['Title', 'Price', 'Sponsored','url', 'asin', 'index_asin'])

for url in urls:
    print('URL',url)
    sleep(randint(10,15))
    response = requests.get(url)

    print('Response ')
    print(response)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers= headers).text, 'lxml') #lxml

    for div in soup.select('div[data-asin]'):
        title, price = div.select_one('span.a-text-normal').text, div.select_one('.a-offscreen').text if div.select_one('.a-offscreen') else '-'
        sponsored = 'Yes' if div.select_one('span:contains("Sponsored")') else 'No'
        url = response.url
        asin = div['data-asin']
        try:
          index_asin = div['data-index']
        except:
          index_asin='NAN'
        print('title', title)

        #print('title',title)
        #print('price',price)
        #print('sponsored',sponsored)
        #print('url',url)
        #print('asin',asin)
        #print('index_asin',index_asin)

        # I want to store everything in a data frame
        df=df.append({'Title':title,'Price':price,'Sponsored':sponsored,'url':url,'asin':asin,'index_asin':index_asin},ignore_index=True)
```

Error:

```
runfile('C:/Stack_Test.py', wdir='C:/Users/.....')
URL https://www.amazon.com/s?k=shaver&ref=nb_sb_noss_1
Response 
<Response [200]>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-41472a103f02>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('.../Stack_Test.py', wdir='C:/...')

  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/.../Stack_Test.py", line 31, in <module>
    title, price = div.select_one('span.a-text-normal').text, div.select_one('.a-offscreen').text if div.select_one('.a-offscreen') else '-'

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: which line of code gives error ?

Comment: different User-Agent may means different devices and server may send different HTML for different devices. Some devices may get data with expected tag and other may not have this tag and then you may get `None`

Comment: if you use headers then maybe you should use them in all `get()`, `post()`.   And you could use `requests.Session()` to keep cookies between requests.

Comment: I don't know way you get page two times - first without headers, next with headers. You could get it once, display i and next use it in `BS`

Comment: @furas thanks. I added the full error in the post (see updated)

Comment: error shows `select_one()` gives `None` so you have `title = None.text`. It means it can't find `'span.a-text-normal'` in HTML. You should use `if/else` like for `price` or better display HTML (or write in file and display in browser) to see what you have in HTML - maybe there is message or warning that this User-Agent is blocked. Or it sends data in different tags for different device.

Comment: This has nothing to do with UA, amazon sends various different layouts, it's called A/B testing

Comment: @pguardiario thanks, but how is it possible that the UA (with the comment #works) often works, while the others are throwing errors?

Comment: You're imagining it. You randomly got the layout you expected.